# Bypass OpenDNS and use ISP DNS servers for CDNs (DD-WRT)

Tags: router, dns, dd-wrt, opendns, cdn

I'm using OpenDNS at home with a DD-WRT router (Buffalo Airstation). While OpenDNS is great for many things, Content Delivery Networks don't play nice with it. I noticed this when I tried to rent a movie on iTunes and the playback was very choppy.

Is there a way in DD-WRT to specify different DNS servers to use for specific domain name lookups?

Basically I want *.apple.com to be resolved using the ISP DNS servers instead of the router configured OpenDNS servers.

Comment: Not sure what DNS server DD-WRT is running.  If it is DNSMasq, then it should be possible to do this, assuming you have a list of CDNs.  I am not aware of any list of CDNs though.

Comment: @Zoredache Yes, it does have DNSMasq on it. Say, instead we want to allow *.apple.com to be resolved using the ISP DNS servers instead of the router configured OpenDNS servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done. We need to take advantage of a seldom-used *dnsmasq* configuration feature, the statement *server*.

You can find how to use it in [Arch Linux wiki on dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq#Prevent_OpenDNS_Redirecting_Google_Queries), where it is stated:

> To prevent OpenDNS from redirecting all Google queries to their own search server, add to /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
  server=/www.google.com/<ISP DNS IP>
```

It is clear that you can achieve the result you inquired about by means of the statement:

```
  server=/www.apple.com/<ISP DNS IP>
```

where you will have to substitute your ISP DNS IP, which you did not provide in your OP.

This statement can be placed in the box *Additional DNSMasq Options*, which you can find in the panel *Services*, under the heading *DNSMasq*. You will have to enable both functions of DNSMasq,, and place the above line in the box *Additional DNSMasq Options*.

Save, restart, you are done.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and if it works you'll get the accepted answer and bounty. I'll get back to you real soon.

Comment: Looks like it's working. iTunes seems to load content faster. As I live with the change, I'll post here if anything seems to not work.

Comment: It worked! iTunes is much smoother now. Thanks.